# Выделить определенную последовательность regexp. Регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Необходимо выделить последовательность идущих друг за другом ссылок
`<a></a>, <a></a>`

Внутри `<a></a>` Могут быть любые символы, например `<a>**<span></span>**</a>,`

Но если между ссылками `<a></a>` есть другие теги, например `<a></a></span>, <a></a>`, то такую последовательность брать не стоит

Единственное, что пока приходит в голову это

`(<a>.*<\/a>)` Но данное выражение цепляет все между Первым `<a>` в строке и последним  `</a>`

Исходные данные:

1.`<p><a><span></span></a>, <a></a>, <a></a></p>`

2.`<p><span><a></a><span><a></a>, <a></a></p>`

Должно выбираться:

1. `<a><span></span></a>, <a></a>, <a></a>`
2. `<a></a>, <a></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендуется к прочтению - [Жадные и ленивые квантификаторы](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy). А выражение будет следующим:

```
/(<a>.*?<\/a>)/gi
```

```js
let rExp = /(<a>.*?<\/a>)/gi;
let sTxt = `
  1. <p><a><span>1</span></a>, <a>2</a>, <a>3</a></p>
  2. <p><span><a>4</a><span><a>5</a>, <a>6</a></p>
`;
console.log(sTxt.match(rExp));
```